# Editing a specific place with notepad++

Tags: text, replace, notepad, stac

I need to replace a text in Notepad++. How can i do?

Text:

```
(1, 1, 'qweq123we123'),
(2, 1, 'qwe5qw123e42'),
(3, 1, 'qweq1233we61'),
(4, 1, 'qwe41qdw613e'),
(5, 1, 'qweq12f3w41e'),
(6, 1, 'qw21233eaqwe'),
(7, 1, 'qw5123ge3qwe'),
```

Replaced Text:

```
{"id":1,"ilid":1,"qweq123we123"}
{"id":1,"ilid":2,"qwe5qw123e42"}
{"id":1,"ilid":3,"qweq1233we61"}
{"id":1,"ilid":4,"qwe41qdw613e"}
{"id":1,"ilid":5,"qweq12f3w41e"}
{"id":1,"ilid":6,"qw21233eaqwe"}
{"id":1,"ilid":7,"qw5123ge3qwe"}
```

separately, i want to convert the result from qw5123ge3qwe to QW5123GE3QWE.

i searched on youtube and stackoverflow but could not find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex search and replace. regex101.com

Search String:

```
\(([0-9]{1,}), ([0-9]{1,}), '([\u0600-\u06FF]{1,})'\)
```

Replace:

```
{"id":\1,"ilid":\2,"\U\3"}
```

\1 \2 \3 are tied to the ([]{1,}) content.
The \U makes anything after it to be uppercase.

[0-9] means any number between 0-9 (single character)

[0A-z0-9] means any number between 0-9 and any character between a-z including the different cases

{1,} this means it must have at least 1 character matching. Everything is done on a single character basis, so if the number is larger than 9 e.g. 10 this is 2 characters a '1' + '0', you could restrict the number of characters by doing something like {1,7}

** [\u0600-\u06FF] ** add as an edit per eyuq's comment below

Comment: i can not replace UTF-8 characters. Such as Ğ, Ü, Ç

Comment: \\(([0-9]{1,}), ([0-9]{1,}), '([\u0600-\u06FF]{1,})'\\) - Resolved